# Saving input to variable so after the program closes it will remember the input

Tags: variables, replace, passwords, save

I am making a program that stores a default password that when entered correctly you can change it. Problem is when I enter the new password it doesn't save when I close and open the program.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

string inputC;
string yes = "yes";
string no = "no";
string password;
string input;

void correct()
{
        cout << "Would you like to change the password?" << endl;
        cin >> inputC;

        if (inputC == yes)
        {
                cout << "Enter new password:" << endl;
                cin >> password;
        }
        else
        {
                cout << "You now have access." << endl;
        }
}

void enter()
{
        cout << "Enter password: " << endl;
        cin >> input;

        if (input == password)
        {
                cout << "Correct" << endl;
                correct();
        }
        else
        {
                cout << "Incorrect" << endl;
                enter();
        }
}
int main()
{
        if (password.empty())
        {
                password = "password";
        }
        enter();
}
```

http://pastebin.com/zhKTW2FB

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please could you add the code to your question, rather than in Pastebin, as this means the question won't become irrelevant if the Pastebin URL changes or is removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, variables you create with code go to RAM Memory, so they are destroyed as soon as your programs finishes. In order to keep the new password, you should consider having it written in an external text file or database.